# LocalBroadcastManager sends data more than once

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a fragment where when a User inputs a link and hits the button, a service is initiated which processes the link and grabs image or videos if there are any on the url...

But my problem is that the same is downloaded more than once like 2 to 3 times..
here is the fragment -

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

FloatingActionButton btn;
EditText et1;
String profilname;
ProgressDialog pd;
private ArrayList<Long> mDownloadIds = new ArrayList<>();



    public FragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two,container, false);

getActivity().registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity())
            .registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION));


FloatingActionButton btn = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    EditText et1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


 pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Let us Check");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
@Override               
public void onClick(View v) { 
EditText et1 = (EditText)

getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
profilname = et1.getText().toString();

((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService("input_method"))                   .hideSoftInputFromWindow(et1.getWindowToken(), 0);                  

profilname.replace("https://www.instagram.com/","https://instagram.com/");

if (profilname.trim().equals("")){ 
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Link is Blank!", 0) 

.show(); 
}

else if(isNetworkAvailable()){

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), profilname, 0) 
.show(); 
    DownloaderService.startActionFoo(getActivity(), profilname);
pd.show();
}

else{
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Error", 0) 
.show(); 
}
}       
    });



return rootView;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
     NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ContentValues contentValues = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.MEDIA_INFO);
            String mediaUrl = contentValues.getAsString(Constants.MEDIA_URL);
            String mediaName = contentValues.getAsString(Constants.MEDIA_NAME);
            pd.dismiss();
            download(mediaUrl, mediaName);

            EditText et1 = (EditText)

getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
et1.setText("");
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            long enqueueId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
            if (mDownloadIds.contains(enqueueId)) {
               /* if (mBtnDownload.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    mBtnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }*/
                getActivity().getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
            }
        }
    };


    public void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void download(String url, String fileName) {

        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/MCD/");
        myDir.mkdirs();

           DownloadManager mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        if (!doesRequestExist(mDownloadManager, url)) {
           /* boolean allowedOverMetered = mSettings.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_NETWORK, true);*/
            int networkType = NETWORK_WIFI | NETWORK_MOBILE;
        /*    if (allowedOverMetered) {
                networkType = NETWORK_WIFI | NETWORK_MOBILE;
            }*/
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setTitle(fileName);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(root + "/MCD/", fileName);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(networkType);

            long id = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
            mDownloadIds.add(id);
        }
    }

    private boolean doesRequestExist(DownloadManager downloadManager, String url) {
        boolean result = false;
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
            | DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING
            | DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int uriIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI);
            String uri = cursor.getString(uriIndex);
            if (uri.equals(url)) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }

    }
```

here's the Downloader Service -

```
public class DownloaderService extends IntentService {
    private static final String ACTION_FOO = "com.parrotainment.media.downloader.action.FOO";

    private static final String EXTRA_URL = "com.parrotainment.media.downloader.extra.URL";

    public DownloaderService() {
        super("DownloaderService");
    }

    public static void startActionFoo(Context context, String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DownloaderService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_FOO);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, url);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_FOO.equals(action)) {
                final String url = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
                handleActionFoo(url);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleActionFoo(String urlStr) {
        try {
            ContentValues mediaInfo = new ContentValues();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlStr).timeout(5000).get();
            Document content = Jsoup.parse(doc.toString());
            String videoUrl = content.getElementsByAttributeValue("property","og:video")
                    .attr("content");
            String title = content.getElementsByAttributeValue("property","og:title")
                    .attr("content").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\u4E00-\\u9FA5\\s]","");

            if (!videoUrl.isEmpty()) {
                String videoName = title + ".mp4";
                mediaInfo.put(Constants.MEDIA_NAME, videoName);
                mediaInfo.put(Constants.MEDIA_URL, videoUrl);
            } else {
                String imgUrl = content.getElementsByAttributeValue("property","og:image").attr("content");
                String imgName = title + ".jpg";
                mediaInfo.put(Constants.MEDIA_NAME, imgName);
                mediaInfo.put(Constants.MEDIA_URL, imgUrl);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.MEDIA_INFO, mediaInfo);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

& the Constants -

```
public final class Constants {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.parrotainment.media.downloader.BROADCAST";
    public static final String MEDIA_INFO = "com.parrotainment.media.downloader.MEDIA_INFO";
    public static final String MEDIA_NAME = "com.parrotainment.media.downloader.MEDIA_NAME";
    public static final String MEDIA_URL = "com.parrotainment.media.downloader.MEDIA_URL";
}
```

Comment: have tried to register your receiver in onResume() method.

Comment: You should unregister your broadcast receiver onDeatch, not on onDestroye.

Comment: @SachinRao i get a crash if I use it onResume

Comment: @HimeshGoswami still same :(

Answer (score 0):

just checking data in your oReceive may help.  like this:

```
if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("your_constant_item")){
```

//
}